# CSS transition on expanding search bar in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an expand-on-hover search form in a Bootstrap 4 navbar. There is a smooth transition on the search form on hover, but the menu next to it jumps abruptly. I've done this layout before with Bootstrap 3 with floated elements, and everything slides over smoothly. It behaves differently with flexbox. I am still learning flexbox -- can everything in the line slide over smoothly without using floats?

[See Example JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rt02nz4j/)

```
#secondaryNav {
  justify-content:flex-end;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

#secondaryNav #searchform {

  .input-group {
    justify-content:flex-end;
  }

  .search-form-control {
     transition: all 0.5s;
     max-width: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
  }    

}

#secondaryNav #searchform:hover {

    .form-control {
        max-width:100%;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a full working example. You need to set width for input in normal state and on focus. Transition is also required for smooth effect.

```css
#search{width:75px;transition:width .5s ease}
#search:focus{width:200px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
    <div class="text-light mr-4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input id="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems the problem was that I was using a percentage for max-width. All I changed was 100% to 200px, and it transitioned the whole line smoothly.